# How to transfer eth to specific address in smart contract?

Tags: remix, ether, etherscan

I want to send eth to specific amount by calling smart contract.

This is my contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

contract MyContract { 　　
　　address payable receiver;

    constructor(address _icb_address) public {
        receiver = msg.sender;
    }

    function sendEther(uint _amount) public returns(bool success) {
        receiver.transfer(_amount);
        success = true;
    }

}
```

I called endEther from an address which is not same as receiver, but I got this error.
`gas required exceeds allowance (10000000) or always failing transaction`

This is failed transaction on etherscan.
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x5652cad647ee5146cdb1e2e97f8376075a630e98021e0927cb629ed0efbe1099

It seems like transfer function is called from contract.
I couldn't understand why this function is executed by contract address not `msg.sender`.

How to send eth to spesific address on smart contract?
Could you give me any advise, please?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction failed because your contract does not have any ETH balance and in your transaction to `sendEther` you also did not include any ETH.

Try either to send ETH to the contract and afterwards call `sendEther` or directly call `sendEther` with enough ETH in the transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought a msg.sender can send ether by calling `address.transfer()` if msg.sender has enough ether not contract. In my case, how to call `sendEther()`with ETH in the transaction?

Comment: I changed function name from endEther to sendEther, sorry for your inconvenience .

Comment: It depends on how you call the contract. If you use Metamask for example you can specify the amount of ETH in the GUI.